# Rails 5 action cable with nobrainer not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rethinkdb, rails-activejob, actioncable

I tried action cable example from https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples. It worked well with ActiveRecord. I am getting **ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: Comment)** when using with NoBrainer for rethinkDB.
So I just passed id instead of self like below for activejob. But action cable server is not able to listen to the any channels and CommentsChannel methods are not invoked.

**comment.rb**

```
after_save { CommentRelayJob.perform_later(self.id) }

*****comment_relay_job.rb*****
def perform(comment_id)
  comment = Comment.find(comment_id)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "messages:#{comment.message_id}:comments",
  comment: CommentsController.render(partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment }
end
```

**comments_channel.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base; end
end

class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def follow(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_from "messages:#{data['message_id'].to_i}:comments"
end

  def unfollow
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

**comments.coffee**

```
App.comments = App.cable.subscriptions.create "CommentsChannel",    collection: -> $("[data-channel='comments']")
  connected: ->
    setTimeout =>
       @followCurrentMessage()
       @installPageChangeCallback()
    , 1000

  received: (data) ->
    @collection().append(data.comment) unless @userIsCurrentUser(data.comment)

  userIsCurrentUser: (comment) ->
       $(comment).attr('data-user-id') is $('meta[name=current-user]').attr('id')

  followCurrentMessage: ->
    if messageId = @collection().data('message-id')
      @perform 'follow', message_id: messageId
    else
      @perform 'unfollow'

  installPageChangeCallback: ->
     unless @installedPageChangeCallback
       @installedPageChangeCallback = true
       $(document).on 'page:change', -> App.comments.followCurrentMessage()
```

Comment: How does the channel look?

Comment: I added the comment channel above.

Comment: Could you post you js as well? Also, try using `data.fetch("message_id")` when geting the id.

Comment: I updated question with coffee script. @perform 'follow', message_id: messageId returns true in my coffee script but my CommentsChannel follow(data) method never called.